# Save .txt file from ftp to documents folder iphone

Tags: iphone, ftp, download

Trying to save a .txt file from an ftp-server to the documents folder on the iPhone.
The file is received and I can write out the content on the screen,
but no file in the documents folder.

Do I mix up things?
I shall not modify the content, just copy from url. Is there an easier way?
I have tried to puzzle codes from difrent posts, but I don't get it right.
Somebody that would be kind to write an complete sample code?

// reading textfile from url //

```
NSURL *urlVersion = [NSURL URLWithString: @"ftp://myftp/Text.txt"];
NSString *webVersion = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urlVersion encoding:1 error:NULL];

//save file to documents//

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *FileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Text.txt", documentsDirectory];
NSString *Content = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", webVersion];
[Content writeToFile:FileName atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil]; 

// displays the content of file onscreen

NSLog(@"Web Version = %@", Content);
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be the encoding issue. Try **NSUTF8StringEncoding** rather then **NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy**.